# List Comprehension Running Sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this code is being executed:

```
def t(xs):
    return [[xs[i][j] for i in range(len(xs))] for j in range(len(xs[0]))]

>>> y = t([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

So I thought the output would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

by setting `for i in range(...)` as the outer loop, but noticed that the output is actually:

```
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

and I'm not sure why, is it because of the first loop is between square brackets so it gets run as the inner loop? When I experimented with this question and removed the brackets I got the answer I was expecting at first, but not sure why and how would the sequence change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[xs[i][j] for i in range(len(xs))] for j in range(len(xs[0]))]
```

is equivalent to

```
result = []
for j in range(len(xs[0])):
    result.append( [] )
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        result[j].append(xs[i][j])

print result
```

`[xs[i][0] for i in range(len(xs))] with j=0` will form inner loop and will return a list,  `for j in range(len(xs[0]))` will form outer loop and will return list of lists.

And when you do

```
[xs[i][j] for i in range(len(xs)) for j in range(len(xs[0]))]
```

it is equivalent to

```
result = []
for j in range(len(xs[0])):
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        result.append(xs[i][j])
```

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense now with the expanded code.

Comment: I believe the `for` loops in that last code example are switched.  `[x for y in z for x in y]` is equivalent to `for y in z: for x in y: result.append(x)`

Comment: Well, order of loop is irrelevant here.. as long as it's logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Starting at `y = t([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`:

`xs` is defined as `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` with the above call

Let us now analyze the possible outputs from each `for` within the list comprehension:

`for j in range(len(xs[0]))` should yield values within the range of `0 <= x <= 2` such that `x` is an integer as an inequality or `[0,1,2]` if we were to represent it as an array.

`for i in range(len(xs))` should yield values within the range of `0 <= x <= 1` such that `x` is an integer as an inequality or `[0,1]` if we were to represent it as an array.

So what actually happens?

There is a list comprehension within a list comprehension so you are going to build arrays within the comprehension.

Starting with the initial value of `j` within the first iteration will yield a reference of `0`. With `i`; it will have two values for `j`. Those values for `i` are going to be `[0,1]` if we represent it as a list.

Thus the first list within the inner comprehension is `[1,4]`.
The 'overall' data representation of the list comprehension at the end of the first iteration of `j` is now `[[1,4]]`

When `j` is `1`; there will again be two possible values for `i`. The values for `i` are `[0,1]` since the cardinality of `xs` is `2`.

When the inner list comprehension of `i` returns; your result will be `[2,5]`. The overall list will look like `[[1,4],[2,5]]` at the end of the second iteration.

Similarly the process will follow for iteration 3 which then yields the result of `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`

The reasoning being the combination of list comprehensions, array/list indexing and the use cases of the `range` function on Python.